# Weighted division with min and max bound?

Tags: fair-division

Let's say I have 10,000 dollars I want divided among 10 people. With simple division each person gets $1,000. Easy enough.

Now suppose each person has a share in a company. I want to divide the money base on their percentage of their shares in company. it is not hard too.

my problem is another rule. we want no one give more than a MAX and less than a MIN amount of money. I know this rule make  fair division impossible. but I want to find an efficient optimum way to do this.

Thanks